# Macros and postincrement

Tags: c, macros, undefined-behavior

Here's some more weird macro behavior I was hoping somebody could shed light on:

```
#define MAX(a,b) (a>b?a:b)

void main(void)
{
  int a = 3, b=4;

  printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b,MAX(a++,b++));
}
```

The output is 4 6 5. The value of b is incremented twice but not before MAX displays its value. Can anybody please tell me why this is happening and how does one predict such behavior? (Another instance of why macros should be avoided!)

Comment: intresting, what happens if you do MAX(++a, ++b)?
i found this information on a forum:
Never use pre or post increment as parameters to macros, as a macro
might use the parameter more than once. As a consequence, item 2
should be "never use increment or decrement on parameters to a
function", as you might not know if this is a real function, or that
this was implemented as a macro.
source: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/759291-beginner-post-increment-question

Comment: This may be considered an argument against using pre or post increment.

Comment: @peko: that said, when standard functions are implemented as macros, they must evaluate each argument exactly once (7.1.4/1). Furthermore the standard libraries always provide the function *as well as* the macro. So `strlen(++s)` increments `s` exactly once, but if you want to avoid the macro anyway you can write `(strlen)(++s)` instead, which isn't a macro infocation. Writers of third-party libraries may or may not provide these helpful guarantees if they provide "things" that they won't tell you whether they're functions or macros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros do text substitution. Your code is equivalent to:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b, a++ > b++ ? a++ : b++);
```

This has undefined behavior, because `b` is potentially incremented (at the end of the third argument) and then used (in the second argument) without an intervening sequence point.

But as with any UB, if you stare at it for a while you might be able to come up with an explanation of what your implementation has actually done to yield the result you see. Order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified, but it looks to me as though the arguments have been evaluated in right-to-left order. So first, `a` and `b` are incremented once. `a` is not greater than `b`, so `b` is incremented again and the result of the conditional expression is `5` (that is to say, `b` after the first increment and before the second).

This behavior is not reliable - another implementation or the same implementation on another day might give different results due to evaluating the arguments in a different order, or theoretically might even crash because of the sequence point issue.

Comment: I kind of understand what is happening once I have the output, but how do I predict such behavior?

Comment: @Appster: you can't (without using a lot of undocumented details of your particular compiler), it's undefined behavior. Never write this code. If you mean, "how can I predict that it's undefined", then a simplified version is that you should never use a variable and also increment it, in the same expression. If the interview question is, "what is the output of this program?", then the correct answer is "I don't care, and if you do then you're a poor C programmer". That may not be the answer most likely to get you the job, but it's correct :-)

Comment: +1 . So basically, a++ > b++ compares 3 > 4? which it is not, so compiler shifts to the right of the : after incrementing a and b to 4 and 5, resp. So the result of MAX when displayed is b=5, and then b is incremented the second time. Think I got it!

Comment: @Appster: that's correct, and `MAX(a++,b++)` on its own has defined (if surprising) behavior, since the `?:` conditional operator has a sequence point between the condition and whichever of the other two expressions is actually evaluated. It's the combination of `MAX` with the additional uses of `a` and `b` in the same expression that's undefined.

Comment: There's a lot of undocumented behavior you notice when you work with C, but careful observation (and lots of test samples) always reveal a pattern. That is what interviewers thrive on, and telling an interviewer that I hardly care would get me thrown out for sure :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a variable and incrementing it in the same expression -- just don't do it TWICE in the same expression.

Comment: @Appster: OK, "don't care" is perhaps a little strong, but all of your careful observation only tells you what one implementation appears to do. Use a different compiler, or different optimization flags, or your left hand instead of your right to hit "enter", it might do something different. That's why formally speaking I don't care what the code does, even if in reality I'm curious enough to have worked out an explanation.

Comment: @Dmitri: yes, for brevity I said "use", really it's "use, other than in the increment". So for example `a + (++a)` has undefined behavior because `a` is used other than in the increment. `b = ++a` of course does not have undefined behavior, even though incrementing `a` inherently uses `a`. `++a && a` also has defined behavior thanks to the sequence point at the `&&` operator, but if you want to rely on that you have to learn it properly rather than use my simplified rule.

Comment: @Steve: that's a better explanation, I think.  Don't "use, other than in the increment".  Following the simpler version would be really inconvenient..

Comment: @SteveJessop I'm trying to understand why printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b,MAX(a+1,b+1)); works, it seems that the compiler deals with that fine. Resulting in a: 3, b:4 and a MAX of 5. -- I suppose this is because x+1 and y+1 do not modify the value of x and y respectively?

Answer (score 2):

In macro, parameters are just replaced by the arguments; so arguments can be evaluated multiple times if they are present multiple times in the macro.

Your example:

```
MAX(a++,b++)
```

Expands to this:

```
a++>b++?a++:b++
```

I think you don't need more explanations :)

You can prevent this by assigning each parameter to a temporary variable:

```
#define MAX(a,b) ({   \
    typeof(a) _a = a; \
    typeof(b) _b = b; \
    a > b ? a : b;    \
})
```

(This one uses several GCC extensions, though)

Or use inline functions:

```
int MAX(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

This will be as good as a macro at runtime.

Or don't do the increments in the macro arguments:

```
a++;
b++;
MAX(a, b)
```

Comment: agreed. it's often much safer to avoid macros as in the inline function in this answer because they are type-safe. also, because they are inline they actually do not result in a stack frame being created and destroyed as a normal function would.

Comment: Type-safe, only evaluate their arguments once, are seen by more debuggers … Just note that using a function instead of a macro here does not remove the UB.

Answer (score 2):

When the preprocessor reads the line it replace the MAX(a++,b++) in the printf to the (a++>b++?a++;b++)

So your function becomes

```
    printf(a,b,(a++>b++?a++;b++));
```

Here order of evaluation is "compiler dependent".

To understand when these conditions can occur u have to understand about Sequence point.

At each sequence point, the side effects of all previous expressions will be completed(all the variable calculation will be completed). This is why you cannot rely on expressions such as:

```
    a[i] = i++;
```

because there is no sequence point specified for the assignment, increment or index operators, you don't know when the effect of the increment on i occurs.
“Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.”. If a program breaks these rules, the results on any particular implementation are entirely unpredictable(undefined).

--The sequence points laid down in the Standard are the following:

1) The point of calling a function, after evaluating its arguments.

2) The end of the first operand of the && operator.

3)The end of the first operand of the || operator.

4)The end of the first operand of the ?: conditional operator.

5)The end of the each operand of the comma operator.

6)Completing the evaluation of a full expression. They are the following:

Evaluating the initializer of an auto object.

The expression in an ‘ordinary’ statement—an expression followed by semicolon.

The controlling expressions in do, while, if, switch or for statements.

The other two expressions in a for statement.

The expression in a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are evaluated by the preprocessor which stupidly replaces all according to the macro definitions. In your case, `MAX(a++, b++)` becomes `(a++>b++) ? a++ : b++`.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm correct, this is happening:

with MAX replaced with (a>b...) you have printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b,(a++ > b++ ? a++ : b++ ) );

First, a++ > b++ is checked and both values increased (a = 4, b = 5) afterwards.
Then the second b++ gets active, but because it's postincrement, it's increased after the second value b = 5 is printed.

Sorry for my bad english, but i hope you understand it?! :D

Greeings from Germany ;-)

Ralf

Answer (score 1):

So your expansion gives (adjusted for clarity):

```
(a++ > b++) ? a++ : b++
```

... so `(a++ > b++)` is evaluated first, giving one increment each and selecting a branch based on the not-yet-incremented values of `a` and `b`.  The 'else' expression is chosen, `b++`, which does the second increment on `b`, which was already incremented in the test expression.  Since it's a post-increment, the value of `b` before the second increment is given to `printf()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for the result that you're getting here:

1. A macro is nothing but code that is expanded and pasted when you compile. So your macro

   ```
   MAX(a,b) (a>b?a:b)
   ```

   becomes this

   ```
   a++>b++?a++:b++
   ```

   and your resulting functions is this:

   ```
   printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b, a++>b++?a++:b++);
   ```

   Now it should be clear why b is incremented twice: first in comparison, second when returning it. This is not undefined behaviour, it is well defined, just analyse the code and you'll see what exactly to expect. (it is predictable in a way)
2. The second problem here is that in C parameters are passed from last to first to the stack, hence all the incrementation will be done before you print the original values of a and b, even if they're listed first. Try this line of code and you'll understand what I mean:

   ```
   int main(void)
   {
       int a = 3, b=4;
       printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b, b++);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

The output will be 3 5 4. 
I hope this explains the behaviour and will help you to predict the result. 
**BUT**, the last point depends in your compiler

Comment: "in C parameters are passed from last to first to the stack" maybe in the ABI used by your implementation, but the standard does not guarantee this. It's not even implementation-defined what order the arguments are evaluated, it is unspecified.

Answer (score -1):

I think the questioner was expecting the output to start:

```
3 4 ...
```

instead of:

```
4 6 ...
```

and this is because the parameters are being evaluated from right to left as they are being pushed onto the stack, that is, the last parameter is being evaluated first and pushed, then the second to last, then the second parameter and finally the first parameter.

I think (and someone post a comment if it's wrong) that this is defined in the C standard (and C++).

*Update*

The order of evaluation is defined, but it's defined as undefined (thanks Steve). Your compiler just happens to do it this way. I think I got confused between evaluation order and the order the parameters are passed.

Comment: 6.5.2.2/10 of C99: "The order of evaluation of the function designator,the actual arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspeciﬁed, but there is a sequence point before the actual call."