# Pre-increment in macro (C)

Tags: c, macros

I got a question about what will this code print. I saw that the answer is 5 but I cant figure out why , what is happening with the ++? where will the value increase exactly? Thank you!

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #define Max(a,b) ((a>b)?a:b)
        int foo(int num1, int num2)
        {
            return Max(num1, ++num2);
        }
        void main()
        {
            int a = 4, b = 3;
            int res = foo(a, b);
            printf("%d\n",res);
            return 0;
        }

    Edit: So I tried to change the code and see if i get the point.
Now what happens after the replacement is: ((4>4++)?4:5++) so when i enter it to the parameter a it should hold the value 6 but I see that its 5 and again i cant get why. Thanks
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define Max(a,b) ((a>b)?a:b)
    int foo(int num1, int num2)
    {
        int a= Max(num1, num2++);
        return a;
    }
    void main()
    {
        int a = 4, b = 4;
        int res = foo(a, b);
        printf("%d\n",res);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: A classical [macro pitfall](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html)

Comment: Note that it is susceptible to other types of pitfals as well. For instance if you pass something like `x & y` as `a` or `b`.

Comment: You'd do better with `static inline int Max(int a, int b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }` for so many reasons.  Also, incrementing `num2` (a local variable) in the `return` (which means it won't be used again) would be a wasted assignment.  You'd use `num2 + 1` if the code were not just an exercise.

Comment: Merely listen to @JonathanLeffler in lieu of finding a solution yourself. I've learnt a host of things in C from him, I offer you to listen him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After macro replacement your `foo()` function looks like

```
int foo(int num1, int num2) {
    return ((num1>++num2)?num1:++num2);
}
```

Now solve below by considering `num1` value as `4` and `num2` value as `3`

```
     Here num2            Here num2
      become 4             becomes 5 
        |                   | 
((num1 > ++num2) ?  num1 :  ++num2)
   |      
(( 4   >   4 )   ?
       |
    false i.e it will return ++num2 as a output & which in turns return 5
```

Side note, Above one is simple ternary operator & here is how it works

```
operand-1 ?  operand-2 : operand-3 ;
```

first `operand-1` is solved, if its result is `true(non-zero)`, `operand-2` will consider as output otherwise `operand-3`. And in your mentioned code `foo()` returns `operand-3` which is `5`.

Comment: I don't know why nobody gives +1 to none of the answers. Arrogance. +1 all of them from me

Answer (score 2):

Macros work by textual replacement, so in your case

```
Max(num1, ++num2)
```

will be replaced by following code before the actual compilation happens:

```
((num1 > ++num2) ? num1 : ++num2)
```

Now you should be able to figure out yourself what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You use a macro to sort the greater value. So your argument `++num2` replace `b`in your macro and give the resulting code:

```
((num1 > ++num2) ? num1 : ++num2);
```

The condition is false because `num1 = 4` and `num2 = 4`, so the second part of your ternary operator is processed... `++num2`again !!
At the end `b = 5`

See this post for more info: [Macros and postincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432124/macros-and-postincrement)