# Why does the value of "l" become 4?

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define MAX(A,B) (A>B)?A:B
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i= 1, j=2;
    int val1 = max(++i, ++j);
    cout<<"i : "<<i<<" j : "<<j<<endl;
    printf("Val2 : %d\n", val1);

    int k = 1, l = 2;
    int val2 = MAX(++k, ++l);
    cout << "k : " << k << " l : " << l << endl;
    printf("Val2 : %d\n", val2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the above code:

i : 2 j : 3

Val2 : 3

k : 2 l : 4

Val2 : 4

But I think it should be:

i : 2 j : 3

Val2 : 3

k : 2 l : 3

Val2 : 3

Could anyone please clarify it briefly?

Comment: OK, this cannot be java and python and c++

Comment: Please use the appropriate tag the distinguishes the language you're using. Python and Java are irrelevant to this.

Comment: Hint: manually expand the MAX macro.

Comment: Try to expand the macro by hand and then think about what the expanded code does.

Comment: OT: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Because `MAX(++k, ++l)` is expanded using text substitution to `(++k > ++l) ? ++k : ++l` which increments either `k` or `l` twice.    That formally gives undefined behaviour, BTW - any result is possible.

Comment: @max1000001   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432124/macros-and-postincrement

Comment: I think the UB in the link you posted stems from incrementing an argument to a function, which isn't the same as `int val2 = (++k > ++l) ? ++k : ++l` . I don't see why this expression causes UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAX here IS NOT a function. If it were a function then it would do what you are expecting it to do. But it is a macro, NOT a function. So `MAX(++k, ++l)` is not equivalent to `++k; ++l; MAX(k, l)` but to `(++k>++l)?++k:++l`.

Comment: ----------->WoW      (++k>++l)?++k:++l

I got it.

Thank you kindly. @Hammerite